# Adding ffmpeg to our Xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, ffmpeg

I have compiled the ffmpeg library and it was successfully created many files inside my folder.

Now I need to implement the same in my Xcode project. What is the best way for adding to my project.

I wish to create one framework but what files I need to add?

I have many .c files and .a files available after compilation.

Comment: Hi @saranjith! Can you help me with that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57952043/how-to-use-ffmpeg-library-in-ios-swift ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In the past I've successfully used [this build script](https://github.com/kewlbear/FFmpeg-iOS-build-script) to integrate ffmpeg.

The pictorial instructions that follow work for both Objective-C and Swift projects, unless otherwise noted.

As a side note, you should make sure ffmpeg is the correct tool for the job. AVFoundation and VideoToolBox are both very powerful tools that Apple provides for doing many video operations.

For late 2018, get the folder from the kewlbear repo which will appear as in the below image, however, there is an additional file build-ffmpeg-iOS-framework.sh. In terminal, cd to that folder.  With the current version, you must run `build-ffmpeg-iOS-framework.sh` , not `build-ffmpeg.sh` to follow the following tutorial:

## Once you've executed the script, you'll have the following files:

[image]

## Copy the FFmpeg-iOS folder to your project:

[image]

## Add the files to your project:

(by dragging and dropping from finder)
[image]

## With these settings:

[image]

## Add the include directory to your headers:

[image]

## Link the required libraries:

[image]

## Add the headers to the bridging header (Swift-only):

```
#import "libavcodec/avcodec.h"
#import "libavdevice/avdevice.h"
#import "libavfilter/avfilter.h"
#import "libavformat/avformat.h"
#import "libavutil/avutil.h"
#import "libswresample/swresample.h"
#import "libswscale/swscale.h"
```

Objective-C simple example:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "libavformat/avformat.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    AVFormatContext *context = avformat_alloc_context();

    return YES;
}

@end
```

And in Swift:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        let context = avformat_alloc_context()

        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: @AllenHumphreys libz.dylib , libbz2.dylib, libiconv.dylib changed . Please update the answer .

Comment: libz.dylib changed to libz.tbd and libiconv.dylib changed to libiconv.tbd . that's it i think. Let me know if i am wrong.

Comment: @AllenHumphreys thanks for your response. I know about ffmpeg usage. i have integrated and used in android. but i am stuck in how to take a reference of integrated libraries as i did from this answer. how can i get its reference in my code so that i can run the ffmpeg commands i know.

Thank you for your generosity

Comment: Would I need to do anything different to use this script to integrate ffmpeg for a MacOS (not iOS) project? I assume I would use the "x86_64" architecture.

Comment: @robamaton I don't think you should need this script at all as ffmpeg (and all the component libraries) can be compiled for macOS using all the standard settings.

Comment: I was still under the impression that I would need to create bridging headers to use Swift, since ffmpeg is in C++. Does that sound right to you? Thanks for your help, by the way, I'm new to this and still getting the lay of the land.

Comment: @robamaton you need to do most of the things in this answer. You asked how to use the script to build, you don’t. Everything else still applies. Retrieve the libs from the normal build process for ffmpeg’s libraries. Also, ffmpeg is almost entirely C. C++ can’t be used directly in Swift.

Comment: hi @Mr.Ahtazaz notice it says **"With the current version, you must run build-ffmpeg-iOS-framework.sh , not build-ffmpeg.sh to follow the following tutorial:"**  beyond that you will have to ask a new question on this site, click "new question".  or, read the notes/questions on the github site.  good luck !

Comment: @Fattie please see this Question, No body help me, Please take a look at this "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57883141/how-to-integrate-ffmpeg-library-in-xcode-project?noredirect=1#comment102189355_57883141"