Efficiently Merging Multiple Videos in iOS: Alternatives to AVFoundation
What is the most efficient way to merge two or more videos into a single video in an iOS application? I've tried using AVFoundation, but it's quite slow.
I have tried different presets (even AVAssetExportPreset1280x720) and the process is still very slow.
Are there any GPU-accelerated frameworks or techniques that can improve the performance?
Here is my current implementation.
func mergeVideos(
    _ items: [VideoItem],
    presetName: String,
    overlay: Overlay?,
    completionHandler: @escaping (Result<URL, Error>) -> Void
) {
    let fileName = "video-\(Date().description)"
    let composition = AVMutableComposition()
    let allItemsAreMuted = items.allSatisfy(\.isMuted)
    guard
        let compVideoTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(
            withMediaType: .video,
            preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
        )
    else {
        return completionHandler(.failure(VideoEditorError.unknown))
    }
    var compAudioTrack: AVMutableCompositionTrack?
    if !allItemsAreMuted {
        compAudioTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(
            withMediaType: .audio,
            preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
        )
        if compAudioTrack == nil {
            return completionHandler(.failure(VideoEditorError.unknown))
        }
    }

    var currentTime = CMTime.zero
    var loadedVideoTracks = [AVAsset: AVAssetTrack]()
    var loadedAudioTracks = [AVAsset: AVAssetTrack]()
    items.forEach { item in
        do {
            var audioTrack: AVAssetTrack?
            let range = item.range ?? CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero, duration: item.asset.duration)
            var scaledDuration: CMTime?
            if let rate = item.rate, rate != 1 {
                scaledDuration = CMTime(seconds: range.duration.seconds / Double(rate), preferredTimescale: 1000)
            }
            if let videoTrack = loadedVideoTracks[item.asset] ?? item.asset.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first {
                loadedVideoTracks[item.asset] = videoTrack
                try compVideoTrack.insertTimeRange(range, of: videoTrack, at: currentTime)
            }
            if !item.isMuted {
                audioTrack = loadedAudioTracks[item.asset] ?? item.asset.tracks(withMediaType: .audio).first
                if let audioTrack = audioTrack {
                    loadedAudioTracks[item.asset] = audioTrack
                    try compAudioTrack?.insertTimeRange(range, of: audioTrack, at: currentTime)
                }
            }
            if let scaledDuration = scaledDuration {
                let currentRange = CMTimeRangeMake(start: currentTime, duration: range.duration)
                compVideoTrack.scaleTimeRange(currentRange, toDuration: scaledDuration)
                compAudioTrack?.scaleTimeRange(currentRange, toDuration: scaledDuration)
            }
            currentTime = CMTimeAdd(currentTime, scaledDuration ?? range.duration)
        } catch {
            completionHandler(.failure(error))
            return
        }
    }

    let exportURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory())
        .appendingPathComponent(fileName)
        .appendingPathExtension("mov")
    guard let export = AVAssetExportSession(
        asset: composition,
        presetName: presetName
    ) else {
        completionHandler(.failure(VideoEditorError.unknown))
        return
    }

    if let overlay = overlay {
        let videoInfo = orientation(from: loadedVideoTracks.first!.value.preferredTransform)
        let videoSize: CGSize
        if videoInfo.isPortrait {
            videoSize = CGSize(
                width: loadedVideoTracks.first!.value.naturalSize.height,
                height: loadedVideoTracks.first!.value.naturalSize.width
            )
        } else {
            videoSize = loadedVideoTracks.first!.value.naturalSize
        }

        let overlayLayer = CALayer()
        overlayLayer.contents = overlay.image.cgImage
        overlayLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: videoSize.width, height: videoSize.height)
        overlayLayer.opacity = 1
        overlayLayer.masksToBounds = true
        overlayLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(overlay.rotationDegrees, 0, 0)

        let radians = CGFloat(overlay.rotationDegrees) * .pi / 180.0
        overlayLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(radians, 1, 0, 0)

        let videoLayer = CALayer()
        videoLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: videoSize.width, height: videoSize.height)

        let animationLayer = CALayer()
        animationLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: videoSize.width, height: videoSize.height)
        animationLayer.addSublayer(videoLayer)
        animationLayer.addSublayer(overlayLayer)

        // Add the animation layer to the video composition
        let videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition(propertiesOf: composition)
        videoComposition.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(
            postProcessingAsVideoLayers: [videoLayer],
            in: animationLayer
        )
        export.videoComposition = videoComposition
    }

    export.outputURL = exportURL
    export.outputFileType = .mov
    export.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
    export.exportAsynchronously {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            switch export.status {
            case .completed:
                completionHandler(.success(exportURL))
            default:
                completionHandler(.failure(export.error ?? VideoEditorError.unknown))
            }
        }
    }
}


Can you describe what kind of merging, the formats involved, and what you tried in AVFoundation?

I have multiple local videos (mov or mp4) and I want to merge them into the one. I use AVMutableComposition/AVAssetExportSession. The only problem I'm facing is that it is very slow.

Don't doubt it, AVFoundation uses VideoToolbox under the hood, it is already hardware accelerated. There is no faster way.

Merging 2-3 videos of total length less then 10-15 seconds and adding one image overlay takes more 30 seconds.
How can this be the fastest way? What solution do apps like IG or TikTok use then?

Videos using the same codec can be concatenated without re-encoding. I’m not sure it’s possible with AVFoundation. But ffmpeg can do it https://stackoverflow.com/a/49373401/5099014. In the past I also used MP4Box to do similar things. You can also trim videos very quickly this way if you’re ok working on key frame boundaries.

@allenh, do you know how to add dependency to FFmpeg? I use SPM.

@LevanKaranadze  It's been many years, it's possible there's a smoother/less manual way, but I would guess these instructions still work https://stackoverflow.com/a/45614611/5099014. Keep in mind, this gives you the library, not the CLI interface.

I've tried FFmpeg and it's also very slow. Event slower. Here is my command:
let ffmpegCommand =             "\(inputs) -filter_complex \"\(concatFilter)\(overlayFilter)\" -map \"[v]\" -map \"[a]\" -fps_mode vfr -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -crf 23 -threads 4 -c:a aac -b:a 192k \(outputFilePath)"

Maybe the process is slow because of the video dimensions? (assetTrack.naturalSize: 1170.0, 2532.0.)

That ffmpeg command is re-encoding the video and audio.
